# Display colored strings in small font size

Tags: color, size, colorbox

I want to display random strings made up of 's' and 'f' such that every s is white on a blue background and every f is white on a red background. I can make it work fine in normal text, but when I want to display it in \scriptsize it seems to not get small enough.

The code I'm using is:

```
\newcommand{\ss}[0]{\colorbox{blue}{\textcolor{white}{{\texttt{\scriptsize{s\strut}}}}}}
\newcommand{\ff}[0]{\colorbox{red}{\textcolor{white}{{\texttt{\scriptsize{f\strut}}}}}}
```

and then when I want to show a string I write something like:

```
\ss\ff\ss\ff\ff\ff\ss\ss
```

Comment: Could it do with the fact that `\ss` is an already defined LaTeX macro, so your code is generating errors?  Correcting that, this seems to work fine: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\sss}[0]{\colorbox{blue}{\textcolor{white}{{\texttt{\scriptsize{s\strut}}}}}}
\newcommand{\ff}[0]{\colorbox{red}{\textcolor{white}{{\texttt{\scriptsize{f\strut}}}}}}
\begin{document}
sf \sss\ff\sss\ff\ff\ff\sss\sss
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use a simpler macro, as far as usage is concerned.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\fs}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \firth_fs:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \firth_fs:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {f}{\__firth_fs_box:nn { red } { f }}
    {s}{\__firth_fs_box:nn { blue } { s }}
    % add more cases if needed
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__firth_fs_box:nn
 {
  \colorbox{#1}
   {
    \color{white}
    \use:c { check@mathfonts }
    \fontsize { \use:c{ sf@size } } { 0 } \selectfont
    #2 \vphantom{f} % possibly 'fy' if letters with descenders are used
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X \fs{sfsfffs} X

\medskip

\Large X \fs{sfsfffs} X

\medskip

\footnotesize X \fs{sfsfffs} X

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even enter

```
\fs{s f s fff s}
```

as spaces are ignored.

Comment: In my humble opinion, all your answers are beautiful. Just an aesthetic consideration. Would the position of the letters inside the coloured boxes not be an optimal solution if they were aligned with the two X's? My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano That depends on what's the intended usage. The X's are just to show the size relationships.

Comment: Thanks this is amazing! But one small thing- it doesn't work inside tables (just shows black text on white background). How can I make this work inside my tables (I use booktabs for tables, if thats important)?

Comment: @JohnFirth I tried a simple `tabular` and see no issue.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome here!

As said in the comments, `\ss` is already defined, so you need either to redefine it or define another command for printing the s.

However, `\strut` is a `\vrule` of 8.5pt height, 3.5pt depth and a width of 0pt.

That doesn't fit automagically to scriptsize. But you can adapt `\strut`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\strut}{\vrule height5pt depth0pt width0pt}
\renewcommand{\ss}[0]{\colorbox{blue}{\textcolor{white}{{\texttt{\scriptsize{s\strut}}}}}}
\newcommand{\ff}[0]{\colorbox{red}{\scriptsize\textcolor{white}{{\texttt{{f\strut}}}}}}



\begin{document}
\ss\ff\ss\ff\ff\ff\ss\ss
\end{document}
```

See:

[image: pic of code compiled]

However, changing `\strut` or redefining `\ss` may have unwanted side effects. Maybe instead of redefining strut, give it another name `\turts`, e.g. Same for `\ss`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know strut worked like that.